# Threads running amuck with AsyncHttpClient and Quartz Job

Tags: java, multithreading, http, quartz-scheduler, jvisualvm

Here is a simple Quartz scheduler which should run a job **once every minute**; the job in itself makes an HTTP request using the Sonatype [Async Http Client](https://github.com/sonatype/async-http-client). Using `jvisualvm`, I was able to detect threads spawning and never closing, e.g. they are stuck in **wait**. This leads me to believe that either A) I'm misunderstanding how Quartz works with this particular setup, or B) Something else is wrong. Probably A :) The scheduler:

```
public class QuartzAsyncHttpThreadTest {

    /* TEST */
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private static Class jobToRun = AsyncHttpRequestJob.class;
    private static String cron = "0 0/1 * * * ?";
    /* TEST */


    public static void main(String[] args) throws SchedulerException {

        Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
        scheduler.start();

        start(scheduler, jobToRun.getName(), jobToRun);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public static void start(Scheduler scheduler, String name, Class job)
            throws SchedulerException {

        JobKey monitorKey = new JobKey(name + "_job", "jobs");
        JobDetail detail = JobBuilder.newJob(job).withIdentity(monitorKey)
                .build();

        Trigger cronDef = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                .withIdentity(name + "_trigger", "triggers")
                .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(cron)).build();

        scheduler.scheduleJob(detail, cronDef);

    }

}
```

The job:

```
public class AsyncHttpRequestJob implements Job {

    public AsyncHttpRequestJob() {

    }

    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
            throws JobExecutionException {

        System.out.println("Go..");

        makeRequest();

    }

    public static void makeRequest() {

        try {

            Future<Response> r = new AsyncHttpClient().prepareGet(
                    "http://google.com").execute();

            Response response = r.get();

            System.out.println("Request status: " + response.getStatusCode()); // 301

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

There's really not much to it. If I profile live threads, the encroachment is noticeable after 2 minutes. First 24, than 27, 30...and so on. [image]

**EDIT**:

I was able to verify that it's a combination of the AsyncHttpClient and Quartz, as when I swap out the `makeRequest` method with a standard request:

```
    URL conn = new URL("http://google.com");
    URLConnection httpR = conn.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            httpR.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();
```

All works as expected.

Comment: Can you make a thread dump of threads that are stuck (e.g. using `jvisualvm`)? Are they hanging on `r.get()`? Is `"Request status: "` ever displayed? And why are using asynchronous client if you still wait for the response synchronously?

Comment: From the doc, it said that this was the blocking way to use it, no? So I figured it shouldn't matter. I do see "Request status" logged. I can make a dump of threads, but what appears every go-round is that AsyncHttpClient-Reaper thread depicted in the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must close every `AsyncHttpClient` instance created here:

```
Future<Response> r = new AsyncHttpClient().prepareGet(
                "http://google.com").execute();
```

using [`close()`](http://sonatype.github.com/async-http-client/apidocs/reference/com/ning/http/client/AsyncHttpClient.html#close%28%29) method. Each instance of `AsyncHttpClient` creates some resources (like threads) that have to be cleaned-up).

However, since `AsyncHttpClient` is thread-safe, much better approach is to create only one, global instance of `AsyncHttpClient` and reuse it throughout the lifetime of your application and from multiple threads.

Finally, since you basically send some request and wait synchronously (blocking) for a response, why not use standard `URLConnection` (as in your example) or [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/)? `AsyncHttpClient` is great when you don't want to wait for a response synchronously, e.g. when you want to initiate hundreds of HTTP requests concurrently without spawning hundreds of threads. `AsyncHttpClient` will then call your callback code as responses appear.